# JavaScript Reset Input with a Condition

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reset

I am trying to reset some `input` fields for a login if the `loginDiv` display is none, however it is not working at all.

Desired Outcome: click the login button, so long as the `loginDiv` display is none, the two input fields will be reset.

Here is my code:

```js
// LOGIN
const logDiv = document.getElementById('loginDiv');
const wrong = document.getElementById('wrong');
const user = document.getElementById('user');
const pass = document.getElementById('pass');
const log = document.getElementById('logBtn');

log.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (user.value == 'f' && pass.value == 'f') {
    logDiv.style.display = 'none';
    wrong.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    wrong.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

// LOGOUT

const logout = document.getElementById('logout');

logout.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (logDiv.style.display == 'none') {
    logDiv.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

function resetForm() {
  if (logDiv.style.display == 'none') {
    user.reset();
    pass.reset();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loginDiv">
  <input id="user" type="text" placeholder="username"></input>
  <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>
  <button id="logBtn" onclick="resetForm()">login</button>
</div>
<div id="wrong" style="display: none;">
  <p id="wrongText">incorrect login info.</p>
</div>

<div id="logoutDiv">
  <button id="logout" type="button">logout</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: none` actually **removes** the element from the DOM, meaning that JavaScript no longer has access it to. Considering your fields are inside the DIV you're trying to remove, what you're trying to achieve is impossible. You can achieve the desired result with `visibility: hidden` if that helps though.

Comment: @ObsidianAge You're wrong. Setting `display: none` doesn't remove it from the DOM, it simply sets the CSS `display` property to `none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the value of user and password textbox to empty string after the username and password has been verified.

```
user.value = "";
pass.value = "";
```

```js
// LOGIN
const logDiv = document.getElementById('loginDiv');
const wrong = document.getElementById('wrong');
const user = document.getElementById('user');
const pass = document.getElementById('pass');
const log = document.getElementById('logBtn');

log.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (user.value == 'f' && pass.value == 'f') {
    user.value = "";
    pass.value = "";
    logDiv.style.display = 'none';
    wrong.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    wrong.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

// LOGOUT

const logout = document.getElementById('logout');

logout.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (logDiv.style.display == 'none') {
    logDiv.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

function resetForm() {
  if (logDiv.style.display == 'none') {
    user.reset();
    pass.reset();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loginDiv">
  <input id="user" type="text" placeholder="username"></input>
  <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>
  <button id="logBtn" onclick="resetForm()">login</button>
</div>
<div id="wrong" style="display: none;">
  <p id="wrongText">incorrect login info.</p>
</div>

<div id="logoutDiv">
  <button id="logout" type="button">logout</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add some explanation - don't just post code as an answer.

Comment: simplest way. Guess I was overthinking.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can'n click to button login , if this button is not visible , and you
can reset data in input trougth next code:

```
function resetForm() {
    user.value='';
    pass.value='';
}
```

I think that best way is using resetForm in

```
 logDiv.style.display = 'none';
    wrong.style.display = 'none';
    resetForm();
```

Using onclick is not good way, because your code has many location.

Full code for example :
HTML:

```
  <div id="loginDiv">
      <input id="user" type="text" placeholder="username">
      <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="password">
      <button id="logBtn">login</button>
    </div>
    <div id="wrong" style="display: none;">
      <p id="wrongText">incorrect login info.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="logoutDiv">
      <button id="logout" type="button">logout</button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
//LOGIN
      const logDiv = document.getElementById('loginDiv');
      const wrong = document.getElementById('wrong');
      const user = document.getElementById('user');
      const pass = document.getElementById('pass');
      const log = document.getElementById('logBtn');

      log.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (user.value == 'f' && pass.value == 'f') {
          logDiv.style.display = 'none';
          wrong.style.display = 'none';
          resetForm();
        } else {
          wrong.style.display = 'block';
        }
      });

      // LOGOUT

      const logout = document.getElementById('logout');

      logout.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (logDiv.style.display == 'none') {
          logDiv.style.display = 'block';
        }
      });

      function resetForm() {

        user.value = '';
        pass.value = '';
      }
```